# opening a new activity by the combination of two spinners

Tags: java, android-studio

In my MainActivity, I have created 2 spinners having items a1,a2,a3 &b1,b2,b3 each respectively. On clicking the ok button, I want to open activity1 when a1&a2 are selected, activity2 when a1&b2 are selected, activity3 when a1&b3 are selected, activity4 when a2&b1 are selected, activity5 when a2&b2 are selected, and so on.. Can someone help me with this please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: if my answer is working mark it as accepted answer , thakns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `if else` statement or `switch case` statement to check which item are selected and then open your desired activity upon the result

Something like this :

```
if (firstSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("a1")){
        if (secondSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("b1")) {
            //open activity1
        }
        else{
            //open activity2
        }
    }
    else {
        //check for the rest 
    }
```